# How is a for loop written in Perl?

Tags: perl

How do you write a `for` loop in Perl? I've tried the following to no avail:

```
my $i = 0;
for my $foo; do
    $i=$[i+1];
done < bar;
```

Comment: what is supposed to loop over what?

Comment: Have you read the Perldoc page on [Perl syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops)?

Comment: That is not Perl code.

Comment: Ever heard of google?

Comment: `[I'm feeling lucky]` http://perlmaven.com/for-loop-in-perl

Comment: I assume you were just trying to make a point with this post, but it could genuinely be helpful for someone in the future, so I've edited out the inflammatory language and made it more generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two types of for loop in perl, in addition to the for statement modifier.  They look like this:

```
# c-style for loop
for ( my $i = 0; $i < 12; ++$i ) {
    ...
}

# regular for loop
for my $i (0..11) {
    ...
}

# statement modifier
... for 0..11;
```

Answer (score 2):

To write a `for` loop in Perl the syntax would look like this:

```
for my $foo (@array) {
    print "$foo\n";
}
```

Comment: Do not use `my` as a variable name, as [my()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) use in Perl for variable declaration.

Comment: Its not a reserved variable name.

Comment: Its always a good practice to _not_ use any _function_ name as a variable name.

Comment: It's not a reserved word, but it _is_ potentially confusing to maintenance programmers.

Answer (score 0):

for

```
for(my $i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    something...
}
```

or foreach

```
my @names = qw(Steve Bill Connor Bradley);
foreach my $name (@names) {
    something...
}
```

Comment: `for` and `foreach` are aliases to each other, so it is the syntax, not the word that determines which kind of for-loop is used.

Comment: always use strict; use warnings;

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of a for loop in Perl is:

```
for ( init; condition; increment )
{
   statement(s);
}
```

Example:

```
for (my $i=0; $i <= 9; $i++)
{
   print "$i\n";
}
```

Comment: `for` loops are awkward for all but the simplest of cases. The above can be replaced with a `foreach` loop: `for my $i ( 0 .. 9 ){ print "$i\n"; }` The rule of thumb is: for bounded loops, use `foreach`; for unbounded ones, use `while`.

Comment: OP is asking for `for loop` in Perl. And I think I have given a right syntax, so there is no meaning of down vote. It can be improve by editing.

Comment: @shawnhcorey I assume you mean "C-style loops are awkward...", since `for` and `foreach` [are synonyms](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) and can be used interchangeably.

Comment: @shawnhcorey Of course, `perlsyn` uses the same confusing terminology, even after mentioning that the keywords are equivalent.

Comment: Because it comes from Perl 4. :) Back then, `foreach` had only one meaning, the iteration loop.

Comment: C-style for loops can be very nice, `for (my $entry=$linked_list->head; $entry; $entry=$entry->next)` for instance